# Drools Flow: Try to implement looping concept using Drools Flow

Tags: drools, jrules, drools-flow

I need to implement looping concept using drools flow. Actually we are migrating ILog Jrule to Drools. In Existing solution, we have a flow which contain looping.

Kindly find same in attached image, it is in Jrule implementation. we need to convert into Drools flow.

Please help me to resolving the problem.

[image]

- Fetch Node Contains : first element of list.
- Validations Node contains : multiple rules decision tables.
- Remove Node contains:  remove current element which was fetch in Fetch Node.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for work to be done for free.

Comment: I need some idea,thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for above specified problem.
[image]

First conditional control is Gateway Converge(Marge) and second one is Gateway Diverge( Split)